# How to change tree object class or plot nicely trees

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tree, rpart

I need to plot a nice tree for a project. The problem is that I have to use a specific function to create the tree that creates a tree datatype and all the functions used to plot trees in a nice way  (ggtree, rpart.plot) require other types of object. Could you please help me to change the object data type of the tree or suggest me other functions to plot them?
I have to plot `prune.result`. I cannot use other functions to create and prune the tree.
(I know I can use the simply `plot` function but I use the ggplot package in all the project so I would like something similar to that).

Thank you in advance

```
dataframe <- data_frame(y = as.factor(rbinom(1000, size = 1, prob = 0.3)), x0 = rnorm(1000), x1 = rnorm(1000, 3), x2 = rnorm(1000, 3,0.5),  x3 = rnorm(1000, 1,0.5), x4 = rnorm(1000, 3.5), x5 = rnorm(1000, 2.3,0.5),  x6 = rnorm(1000, 1,0.5), x7 = as.factor(rbinom(1000, size = 4, prob = 0.5)), x8 = as.factor(rbinom(1000, size = 3, prob = 0.8)))

library(tree)
tree = tree::tree(y ~., data=dataframe, split='gini', control = tree.control(nobs=dim(dataframe)[1],mincut=1,minsize=2))
prune.result = prune.misclass(tree, best =12)
```

I tried to transform the prune.result into a dataframe to use it into ggtree and I also tried to convert it into an rpart object but I didn't manage.

Comment: Your code doesn't work properly (`tree = ...`) for me. However, look at this link: https://www.edureka.co/blog/implementation-of-decision-tree/

Comment: Now it should work. Thank you, but in this article they use another function that i can't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to work with tree objects produced by the `tree` package, but you want ggplot output, you should check out `ggdendro`

Here's a full reprex based on your example:

```r
set.seed(1)

dataframe <- data.frame(y = as.factor(rbinom(1000, size = 1, prob = 0.3)), 
                        x0 = rnorm(1000), 
                        x1 = rnorm(1000, 3), 
                        x2 = rnorm(1000, 3,0.5),  
                        x3 = rnorm(1000, 1,0.5), 
                        x4 = rnorm(1000, 3.5), 
                        x5 = rnorm(1000, 2.3,0.5),  
                        x6 = rnorm(1000, 1,0.5), 
                        x7 = as.factor(rbinom(1000, size = 4, prob = 0.5)), 
                        x8 = as.factor(rbinom(1000, size = 3, prob = 0.8)))

library(tree)
library(ggdendro)

tree <- tree(y ~ ., data = dataframe, split = 'gini', 
                  control = tree.control(nobs = nrow(dataframe),
                                         mincut = 1, minsize = 2))

prune.result <- prune.misclass(tree, best = 12)

ggdendrogram(prune.result, theme_dendro = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>